# Start of line character in lstlisting

Tags: listings

In `lstlisting` I can use `\^^M` to denote the end of a line in `morecomment`. Is there a similar character to find the start of a line?

Comment: "*to find* the start of the line?" Can you elaborate what you mean by that?

Comment: I guess the OP want for example a line with `abc % def` to comment out the `abc` part instead of (normally) `def`.

Comment: @user202729 @Werner exactly: I would like to color/highlight any part between the SoL and the `%` character.

Comment: I guess you can try to left-delimit by newline and right-limit by `%`, but I suspect it will break on lines without any `%` (if the match is lazy/greedy/something)

Answer (score 3):

The following defines a macro `\collectverbenv` that you can use inside the begin part of an environment definition. This macro will start to grab stuff verbatimly until `\end` is reached (with the same environment name). The macro supports a single optional argument (that must be following immediately after `\begin{<env>}` with no spaces!

The macro supports specifying stuff that should be added at the start and end of each line. For end the following example uses `\char_generate:nn \endlinechar { 12 }` (this is needed to rebuild the list correctly with line breaks) and for start it uses `AA`. You can specify whatever you need to fetch your start of line.

This is used inside a custom environment `mylstlisting`. For this the optional argument will be stored inside a token list and then forwarded as the optional argument to a nested `lstlisting` environment. Then a bit of TeX magic (`\scantokens`) is used to let `lstlisting` collect the body itself with its own catcodes and stuff. Et voila, you can detect the start of a line (because you can inject arbitrary tokens there).

See this example (as already said, only injects `AA` at the start of each line):

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \__collectverbenv_processor:n \q_nil
\keys_define:nn { collectverbenv }
  {
     process    .code:n     = \cs_set:Npn \__collectverbenv_processor:n ##1 {#1}
    ,bol        .tl_set:N   = \l__collectverbenv_bol_tl
    ,eol        .tl_set:N   = \l__collectverbenv_eol_tl
    ,optional   .tl_set:N   = \l__collectverbenv_opt_arg_tl
    ,ignore     .int_set:N  = \l__collectverbenv_ignore_int
    ,no-process .code:n     = \cs_set_eq:NN \__collectverbenv_processor:n \q_nil
    ,no-process .value_forbidden:n = true
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \collectverbenvstore { +m }
  {
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l__collectverbenv_body_tl
      {
        \exp_not:o \l__collectverbenv_bol_tl
        \exp_not:n {#1}
        \exp_not:o \l__collectverbenv_eol_tl
      }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \collectverbenvretrieve { m }
  {
    \cs_set_eq:NN #1 \l__collectverbenv_body_tl
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \collectverbenv { +m }
  {
    \keys_set:nn { collectverbenv } {#1}
    \tl_clear:N \l__collectverbenv_body_tl
    \group_begin:
    \__collectverbenv_set_catcodes:
    \tl_if_empty:NTF \l__collectverbenv_opt_arg_tl
      \__collectverbenv_collect:w
      \__collectverbenv_opt_arg:w
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__collectverbenv_set_catcodes:
  {
    \cs_set_eq:NN \do \char_set_catcode_other:N
    \dospecials
    \char_set_catcode_active:N \^^M
  }
\group_begin:
\char_set_catcode_active:N \^^M
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__collectverbenv_collect:w #1 ^^M
  {
    \__collectverbenv_collect_check_end:n {#1}
    \int_compare:nNnTF \l__collectverbenv_ignore_int > \c_zero_int
      {
        \int_decr:N \l__collectverbenv_ignore_int
      }
      {
        \cs_if_eq:NNTF \__collectverbenv_processor:n \q_nil
          {
            \tl_put_right:Nx \l__collectverbenv_body_tl
              {
                \exp_not:o \l__collectverbenv_bol_tl
                #1
                \exp_not:o \l__collectverbenv_eol_tl
              }
          }
          { \__collectverbenv_processor:n {#1} }
      }
    \__collectverbenv_collect:w
  }
\group_end:
\exp_args:NNo
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__collectverbenv_opt_arg:w
  {
    \use_i_ii:nnn \peek_charcode:NTF []
      \__collectverbenv_opt_arg_auxi:w
      {
        \group_end:
        \exp_after:wN \cs_set:Npn \l__collectverbenv_opt_arg_tl {}
        \group_begin:
        \__collectverbenv_set_catcodes:
        \__collectverbenv_collect:w
      }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__collectverbenv_opt_arg_auxi:w
  {
    \group_end:
    \__collectverbenv_opt_arg_auxii:w
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \__collectverbenv_opt_arg_auxii:w { O{} }
  {
    \exp_after:wN \tl_set:Nn \l__collectverbenv_opt_arg_tl {#1}
    \group_begin:
    \__collectverbenv_set_catcodes:
    \__collectverbenv_collect:w
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__collectverbenv_collect_check_end:n #1
  {
    \str_set:Nn \l_tmpa_str {#1}
    \str_remove_all:Nn \l_tmpa_str { ~ }
    \str_if_eq:eeT
      \l_tmpa_str
      { \token_to_str:N \end { \use:c { @currenvir } } }
      \__collectverbenv_collect_end:w
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__collectverbenv_collect_end:w #1 \__collectverbenv_collect:w
  {
    \exp_args:NNNo
    \group_end:
    \tl_set:Nn \l__collectverbenv_body_tl \l__collectverbenv_body_tl
    \exp_args:Ne \end { \use:c { @currenvir } }
  }
\tl_new:N \l__collectverbenv_body_tl


\tl_new:N \l_mylstlisting_opt_tl
\NewDocumentEnvironment { mylstlisting } { }
  {
    \collectverbenv
      {
         bol = AA % <- use whatever you need as a marker for a start of the line
        ,eol = \char_generate:nn \endlinechar { 12 } % <- needed to rebuild the list
        ,ignore = 1 % <- first line (the one containing \begin) is ignored
        ,optional = \l_mylstlisting_opt_tl % <- collect an optional argument
      }
  }
  {
    \group_begin:
    \collectverbenvretrieve \l_tmpa_tl
    \everyeof={\noexpand}
    \exp_args:Nx \scantokens
      {
        \token_to_str:N \begin{lstlisting}
          [{ \exp_not:o \l_mylstlisting_opt_tl }]
        \char_generate:nn { \endlinechar } { 12 }
        \l_tmpa_tl
        \char_generate:nn { \endlinechar } { 12 }
        \token_to_str:N \end{lstlisting}
      }
    \group_end:
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
\begin{mylstlisting}
  \foo
  \bar
\end{mylstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]